FullCalendar `prev()` and `next()` buttons show the wrong month after selecting a month using `gotoDate()
I am using FullCalendar in my React project, and I have an issue with the navigation buttons (prev() and next()) after clicking on a specific month.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
const handleMonthClick = (monthIndex) => {
  const calendarApi = calendarRef.current?.getApi();
  const currentDate = calendarApi.getDate(); // Get the current date
  let c_year = Number(moment(currentDate).format("YYYY"));
  let c_month = Number(moment(currentDate).format("MM"));

  if (calendarApi) {
    // Navigate to the clicked month
    const newDate = new Date(c_year, monthIndex, 1); // monthIndex is 0-based
    calendarApi.gotoDate(newDate);
    setSelectedMonth(monthIndex); // Set the selected month
    setSelectedYear(c_year); // Set the selected year
  }
};

const handleNavigation = (direction) => {
  const calendarApi = calendarRef.current?.getApi();
  const currentDate = calendarApi.getDate();
  let c_year = Number(moment(currentDate).format("YYYY"));
  let c_month = Number(moment(currentDate).format("MM"));

  if (direction === "prev") {
    c_month -= 1; // Decrease month for prev
    if (c_month < 0) {
      c_month = 11; // Wrap around to December
      c_year -= 1; // Decrease the year
    }
  } else if (direction === "next") {
    c_month += 1; // Increase month for next
    if (c_month > 11) {
      c_month = 0; // Wrap around to January
      c_year += 1; // Increase the year
    }
  }

  // Update state with the new year and month
  setSelectedMonth(c_month);
  setSelectedYear(c_year);

  // Navigate to the updated month
  const newDate = new Date(c_year, c_month, 1);
  calendarApi.gotoDate(newDate);
};

Problem:

When I click on a month using handleMonthClick(), the calendar correctly navigates to that month.
However, when I use the prev() or next() buttons after selecting a month, it sometimes shows the wrong month.

For example, after selecting February (month 1) and clicking "next", the calendar might display March correctly, but if I click "prev", it might show December instead of January.



What I’ve tried:

I’ve tried adjusting the selectedMonth and selectedYear states after each month change, but it doesn’t seem to affect the behavior of the prev() and next() buttons.
I’m using calendarApi.gotoDate() to navigate to the selected month, but I’m unsure if this is properly synchronized with the prev() and next() functions.

Question:
How can I fix the issue so that the prev() and next() buttons correctly show the previous and next months after using gotoDate() to navigate to a specific month?

moment(currentDate).format("MM") returns a month from 1 to 12. But your c_month arithmetic is based on the assumption that it runs from 0 to 11.

...and you really don't need momentJS here, if all you're doing is using it to extract the year and the month number from a Date object - the Date object has native methods for that already - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth . Also if you use the native getMonth function, it will return a value from 0 to 11, which fits the assumptions of the rest of your code.

P.S. If this is fullCalendar, it already has "prev" and "next" buttons built-in. You don't need to implement your own.
